# PDO MySQL case sensitive even with utf8_general_ci

Tags: pdo, collation

I have a MySQL table that has utf8_general_ci collation and I am using PDO prepared statements to connect to it.

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=crm;charset=utf8', $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

I am not using a binary query so it is:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM primary_profile WHERE email LIKE :email"); 
$stmt->execute(array('email' => $email));
```

I do not understand why the query is not considered case insensitive and returns false if the case does not match.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run the following:

`SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_name'`

There are collation settings per field as well as per table.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  I think I understand this but it is way over my my comfort level.  It seems very drastic